# Removing HTML Code in Oracle SQL from a CLOB ListAgg value

Tags: html, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

I have some code that brings back standard columns but then a few columns that use the Listagg function to put multiple values into 1 cell rather than have multiple rows. The column called "Notes" stores whatever the notes are as a "CLOB"

The issue is when someone within the organisation saves an email as a note. When the report is run it then outputs the email content enclosed in HTML tags(and a lot of them)

I wanted to remove all html tags from the output leaving just pure text regardless of the note or the formatting.

If the format of the cell wasn't clob this bit of code works fine:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'\s*<[^>]*>\s*',NULL,1,0,'im')
```

but it doesn't do anything against the output that my code is producing.

My code that deals with the listagg and produces the CLOB output is :

```
Note_data_main AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
AI.INVOICE_ID,
AI.INVOICE_NUM,
note.*,
NULL AS ORG_ID,
NULL As Invoice_Date, 
NULL AS HOLD_REASON, 
NULL AS RELEASE_REASON, 
NULL AS Hold_Date, 
NULL AS VENDOR_NAME,  
NULL AS VENDOR_SITE_CODE,
NULL AS Due_Date,
NULL AS DAYS_OVERDUE,
NULL AS SEGMENT1,
NULL AS Days,
NULL AS Requisitioner,
NULL AS CreatedName,
NULL AS Overdue_Status

FROM
AP_INVOICES_ALL AI,
zmm_notes note
WHERE
AI.INVOICE_ID = note.SOURCE_OBJECT_UID(+)

),

JOINAGE AS (
SELECT A.*, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(B.NOTE_TXT,30000) AS Note
FROM INVOICE_DATA A
LEFT JOIN Note_data_main B
ON A.INVOICE_ID = B.SOURCE_OBJECT_UID
),
NOTEDEET AS (

SELECT INVOICE_ID,ORG_ID,INVOICE_NUM,INVOICE_DATE,
HOLD_REASON,VENDOR_NAME,VENDOR_SITE_CODE,
DUE_DATE,DAYS_OVERDUE,SEGMENT1,DAYS,REQUISITIONER,
CREATEDNAME,OVERDUE_STATUS,
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, Note, (chr(10)||'--------------- 
'||chr(10)))).extract('//text()').getclobval(), (chr(10)||'--------------- 
'||chr(10))) AS Notes
FROM 
JOINAGE
GROUP BY 
INVOICE_ID,ORG_ID,INVOICE_NUM,INVOICE_DATE,HOLD_REASON,VENDOR_NAME,
VENDOR_SITE_CODE,DUE_DATE,DAYS_OVERDUE,SEGMENT1,DAYS,
REQUISITIONER,CREATEDNAME,OVERDUE_STATUS
ORDER BY INVOICE_ID
)
```

Below is the current output and what I want to achieve
Current:

```
<p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font></p><p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><font 
face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="3">Good
afternoon Inspector XXX</font></p><p><font face="Arial,Helvetica,sans- 
serif" size="3">

</font></p><p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><font 
face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="3"><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 
125);"><font face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="3">We
have received the attached invoice for payment but unfortunately, we are 
unable
to make payment as there is not enough money on the purchase order for 
which
you are the requester.</font></span></font></p><p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 
0pt;"><font face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="3"><span style="color: 
rgb(31, 73, 125);"><br/></span></font>
```

Expected:

"

Good
afternoon Inspector XXX

We
have received the attached invoice for payment but unfortunately, we are unable
to make payment as there is not enough money on the purchase order for which
you are the requester.
"

I understand that creating functions would handle this situation but i'm working on Oracle BI Cloud so i'm unable to insert and create tables and create any functions to call later on.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: You seem to be using `xmlagg` rather than `listagg`, which is a bit confusing. More importantly you haven't shown how you're apply the `regexp_replace` to your query. Just treating your sample email as either a VARCHAR2 or CLOB string gets the same result - not what you want as the line breaks are off, but it doesn't do *nothing*. It sounds like you're trying to do this to the aggregated result though - why aren't you applying it directly to `Note` *before* you aggregate?

Comment: When I was using regexp in a final select it wasn't removing anything so (Select regexp_replace(notes,,'<.+?>') as Notes from NOTEDEET nothing seemed to be removed. I have taken your advice and moved the regexp up and used it against the column and it's worked. It's so simply but thank you for helping out with it. Like you said though, the breaks are off and still present in the output but that should be easy enough to remove with the addition to the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Alex Poole the solution was putting the regex_replace earlier in the code so it effects the column directly

This is what I changed:

```
JOINAGE AS (
SELECT A.*, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(B.NOTE_TXT,30000),'<.*?>'),'&nbsp') AS Note
FROM INVOICE_DATA A
LEFT JOIN Note_data_main B
ON A.INVOICE_ID = B.SOURCE_OBJECT_UID
)
```